# Proof that $x^3$ is continuous everywhere on $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

If we have $$|x-x_0| < \delta$$
Then,

$$||x| - |x_0|| < |x-x_0| < \delta$$

$$|x| - |x_0| < \delta$$

$$|x| < \delta + |x_0|$$

We need $$|x^3-x_0^3| < \epsilon$$

Thus,

$$|x^3-x_0^3| = |x-x_0|\cdot|x^2 + x_0 x + x_0^2| = |x-x_0|\cdot|x(x+x_0)+x_0^2|$$

$$< \delta(\delta^2 + 3 \delta |x_0| + 3|x_0|^2) $$

Now if I let this equal $\epsilon$ and solve for $\delta$ I will get 3 different values. I am lost on how to proceed. I do not like the method of letting $\delta = 1$ and then at the end taking the minimum of $1$ and some other derived quantity in terms of $\epsilon$. Do I have to do it that way?

Thank you!

Comment: You don't _have_ to do it that way. But not doing it that way means the expression you choose for $\delta$ has to be extra complicated in order to accommodate large values of $\epsilon$. Since the whole point of continuity is to accommodate _small_ $\epsilon$ that's not something we usually care to do. Instead, saying "for all large $\epsilon$, choose $\delta=1$, and for small $\epsilon$, pick $\delta=g(x,\epsilon)$" means that the function $g$ is often just linear in $\epsilon$.

Comment: Oh okay! Now I understand the reasoning behind it. Thanks! Now I do like that method better

Comment: Or prove the product rule for limits

Comment: As an example, for $f(x) = x^2$, if you want to show continuity at $x = 0$, then you can either use the "pick $\delta$ to be at most $1$" thing, and $\delta = \min(1, \epsilon)$ works fine. _Or_ you can not do that, and you will have to pick something like $\delta = \sqrt \epsilon$. At $x = 2$, the corresponding expressions are $\min(1, 5\epsilon)$ versus $\sqrt{\epsilon + 4}-2$, and for general $x$ it's $\min(1, (2|x|+1)\epsilon)$ versus $\sqrt{\epsilon + x^2}-|x|$. The difference is even larger for more complicated functions.

Answer (score 2):

If $\vert x-x_0 \vert<1, $ then $\vert x \vert <\vert x_0 \vert +1$ and so  $$\vert x^2+x_0x+x_0^2\vert \leq \vert x \vert^2+ \vert x_0 \vert.\vert x\vert+\vert x_0 \vert^2$$ $$\hspace{5.1cm} <\color{red}{(1+\vert x_0 \vert)^2}+\vert x_0 \vert\color{red}{(1+\vert x_0 \vert)}+\vert x_0 \vert^2 $$

Therefore we choose $$\delta=\text{min}\;\Bigg(1,\frac{\varepsilon}{(1+\vert x_0 \vert)^2+\vert x_0 \vert(1+\vert x_0 \vert)+\vert x_0 \vert^2}\Bigg)$$ so that $$\vert x^3-x_0^3 \vert < \varepsilon$$